# I get a crash and nullPointer when Filtering through my custom ListView with Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, filter

I have a custom listView with over 100 entries/objects, which is why I want to implement a search/filter function. I've come pretty far, but when I type something in the editText, the app crashes due to a nullPointer here:

`@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }`

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{
MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lw = findViewById(R.id.lw);
    EditText suche = findViewById(R.id.suchen);
    suche.addTextChangedListener(this);

    final ArrayList<Objekt> arrayList = new ArrayList();

    arrayList.add(new Objekt("AAA", "AAA1"));
    arrayList.add(new Objekt("BBB", "BBB1"));
    arrayList.add(new Objekt("CCC", "CCC1"));
    arrayList.add(new Objekt("DDD", "DDD1"));
    arrayList.add(new Objekt("EEE", "EEE1"));
    arrayList.add(new Objekt("FFF", "FFF1"));

    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,arrayList);

    lw.setAdapter(adapter);

    lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selection = arrayList.get(position).getKuerzel();
            if(selection.equals("AAA")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AAA.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (selection.equals("BBB")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BBB.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (selection.equals("CCC")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CCC.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (selection.equals("DDD")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DDD.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (selection.equals("EEE")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EEE.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (selection.equals("FFF")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FFF.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s); //<-- nullPointer here
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
```

}

And this is my CustomAdapter with implemented Filterable, overwritten getFilter etc.:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
Context context;
ArrayList<Objekt> arr, tempArr;
CustomFilter cs;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Objekt> arr) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arr = arr;
    this.tempArr = arr;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arr.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arr.get(position);
    //return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_view_layout,parent,false);

    TextView kuerzel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewKuerzel);
    TextView fullAdress = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullAdress);

    kuerzel.setText(arr.get(position).getKuerzel());
    fullAdress.setText(arr.get(position).getFullAdress());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (cs == null){
        cs = new CustomFilter();
    }

return cs;
}

class CustomFilter extends Filter{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>0) {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<Objekt> filters = new ArrayList<Objekt>();

            for (int i = 0; i < tempArr.size(); i++) {
                if (tempArr.get(i).getKuerzel().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                    Objekt objekt = new Objekt(tempArr.get(i).getKuerzel(), tempArr.get(i).getFullAdress());
                    filters.add(objekt);
                }
            }
            results.count = filters.size();
            results.values = filters;
        }
        else
        {
            results.count = tempArr.size();
            results.values = tempArr;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        arr = (ArrayList<Objekt>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

I'm rather new to the game and screened alot of posts to try to understand why the nullpointer occurs, but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
My logcat

```
2020-06-08 12:19:59.631 22501-22501/com.example.testlistviewformbm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testlistviewformbm, PID: 22501
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter com.example.testlistviewformbm.MyAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.testlistviewformbm.MainActivity.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:109)
```

And also my Objekt class:

```
public class Objekt {

String kuerzel;
String fullAdress;

public Objekt(String kuerzel, String fullAdress) {
    this.kuerzel = kuerzel;
    this.fullAdress = fullAdress;
}

public String getKuerzel() {
    return kuerzel;
}

public void setKuerzel(String kuerzel) {
    this.kuerzel = kuerzel;
}

public String getFullAdress() {
    return fullAdress;
}

public void setFullAdress(String fullAdress) {
    this.fullAdress = fullAdress;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because when you are setting the `listener`, at that moment the `adapter` is not initialized.

And also you have declared a variable `adapter` in class level but again creating local variable adapter and passing the local value to list.

So change the line to `adapter = new MyAdapter(this,arrayList);`

If this doesn't solve the issue then, set the listener after setting the adapter.

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(this,arrayList);
suche.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I simplified the problem a bit to its bare bones:

```
public class StackOverflow extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher
{
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        /* ..*/

        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( this, arrayList );

        ListView lw = findViewById(R.id.lw);
        /*..*/;

        lw.setAdapter( adapter );

        /* ..*/
    }

    /* ..*/

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count )
    {
        adapter.getFilter().filter( s ); //<-- nullPointer here
    }

    /* ..*/
}

class MyAdapter{
    /*...*/
}
```

Now, the `adapter` variable at the location of the `NullPointerException`, i.e. the one that is `null`, is the field, defined at the top of the class:

```
    MyAdapter adapter;
```

This, however, is *not* the same variable as the one in the `onCreate` method:

```
       final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( this, arrayList );
```

It has the same name, and *shadows* the field, but because it is declared itself, is a different variable. It is only accessible ("in scope") within the `onCreate` method, and does not exist in the `onTextChanged`.

Removing the shadowing and initializing the field will solve the `NullPointerException`:

```
       /*deleted: final Adapter*/ adapter = new MyAdapter( this, arrayList );
```

This works, but initializing fields inside methods is not a good practice. It is generally better to initialize fields inside the constructor. However, since it needs the `MainActivity` itself as its context, this does not work here. I recommend refactoring it further to eliminate the need for the `MainActivity` parameter in the `Adapter` constructor, which is out of scope of this answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer! Great help